# Typescript shows error when importing something

Tags: javascript, typescript

[image]

[image]

Why does it show error when using `import`?

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported lodash in your file:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Comment: but i don't want to import loadash,I will include it in my html page.only  I want is typescript show no error.Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> but i don't want to import loadash, I will include it in my html page.

if you've already imported "lodash" in html page, you can use the `declare` keyword in your typescript source like this:

```
declare var _: any;

_.map([1, 2, 3], function(el: number, index: number) {
// ...
});
```

The **declare** keyword is used for [ambient declarations](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/) where you want to define a variable that may not have originated from a TypeScript file.

-- EDIT --

After a [search](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/), I found "lodash" type definition is available at: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash